# Spring Data Mongo: fetch only a specific element of a list

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

This question has been asked a few times but not exactly how I intend it (or years have passed and I hope things have changed).

Using `Spring Data Mongo`'s `MongoRepository` is it possible to fetch from the DB only a given nested element that matches some criteria?

For example, let's suppose I have the following `Customer` document:

```
public class Customer {

  @Id
  private String id;

  private String name;
  private String surname;
  private List<CreditCard> creditCards;
}
```

Is there a way to say "fetch **ONLY** the `CreditCard` with number XXXX?"

At the moment in my code, I find myself having to do this sort of "filtering" in memory because the query returns ***all*** the elements of the list, not only the one that matches my criteria.

I have found several posts mentioning that to cover this necessity is required to declare `CreditCard` as a `Document` itself and use `@DBRef` but I've read on Mongo's documentation that it may reduce significantly query performance.
Also, the `CreditCards` are indeed assigned to a user so I do want them to be nested within that object (because then using `Mongo Compass` it is way easier to understand which `CreditCards` belong to which `Customer`)

Answer (score 0):

```
Criteria c = Criteria.where("creditCards").elemMatch(Criteria.where("number").is("XXXX"));
mongoTemplate.find(new Query(criteria), Customer.class)
```

The `find` will fetch all the customers that has some CreditCard with number = XXXX.

Not sure if it's okay as you wrote **ONLY**

The CreditCard has no `@Document`

Comment: Thank you for your response ShasharT.
The issue here is that that query retrieves all the `crediCards`, not only the one with that number (I've tested it with PostMan)

Comment: The above is just an example. I've a real app and the core issue that i am facing is that once i do query the list i have to do AGAIN (because technically the DB has already done it) the filtering of the elements of the list but this time in-memory using a stream. So more verbosity of the code and more resources.
I'm really surprised that this (i believe) common requirement isn't satisfied by Mongo.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible. Is it really bad if you got all the 2-3 credit cards (average) and all the customers that got such xxxx digits (instead of only one) ? Or in other words - if I may ask from curiosity - is this the real use case, or there's another use case and this demonstrates a performance problem you'd like to prevent. Thanks